# how to override the browser's back?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile web application using jQuery, which has multi forms you can browse through and a splash screen.
I have my own costume back button with its own logic, so I am catching the browser back and forward button click by:

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
        alert("navigation");
});
```

And it works great. Now what I have yet to do, is to stop the browser from actual carry out these operations.

Can anyone please help?
(Please keep in mind this is a mobile app. so it needs to work on android)

Comment: Try to execute `event.stopPropagation();` to stop the event from bubbling up to the browser. But I don't know if this is possible cause you wan't to change browsers behavior and this could be a security risk and so be permitted by the browser.

Comment: Is it running in PhoneGap or otherwise packaged as native? Or just a standard website? If this is just a website then you're probably stuck.

Comment: It is running as a standalone app on apple, so I don't have a problem there. (since it's on full screen. no back button).
But on Android devices it is running as a standard web application. And even though google said they are gonna support standalone application soon, most android devices has a fiscal back button, so the problem will remain.
Are you sure there is now way to stop the browser from navigating?

Comment: TiMESPLiNTER, thanks for the answer. Yet, I did that:

$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
            event.stopPropagation();
});

But it's not working... not security alerts no nothing...

Comment: you cant, `navigate` is a special event for jQM. You can prevent going back in history within jQM app, but not override browser's default action. check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3V7MH/3/show/), go to last page and then hit back several times.